# Code Vectorization of gsub in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

How can I vectorize this code in R?

```
data <- data.frame(A = rep(5, 5), B = rep(0, 5))
data$abstract <- c("no abstract available", "A", "A", "B", "no abstract available")

for (row in (1:nrow(data))){
  data [row,"abstract"] <- gsub("no abstract available"," ",data[row,"abstract"])
}
```

Comment: Simple R programming questions like this are better asked on Stack Overflow. There are more R experts there and its a bit trivial to call this "Data Science"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have plenty of alternatives for this problem

- **Using sapply**

  ```
  data$abstract <- sapply(data$abstract, 
                          function(x){gsub(pattern = "no abstract available",
                          replacement = " ", x)})
  ```
- **Using mapply**

  ```
  data$abstract <- mapply(gsub, pattern = "no abstract available",
                          replacement = " ", data$abstract)
  ```
- **Using the stringr package**

  ```
  library(stringr)
  data$abstract <- str_replace(data$abstract, "no abstract available", 
                               " ")
  ```

Also, check this [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424709/r-gsub-pattern-vector-and-replacement-vector) for more information, like solutions with match and the qdap package.